# Is this the same moon as in Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, endor

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, a scene takes place in the remains of the second Death Star.

It is mentioned in the script that it’s located on a moon of the Endor system, but it not clear if it’s the same "Forest Moon" of Endor as seen in *Return of the Jedi*.

Is this the same moon? If not, how do the remains of the Death Star end up on a different moon to the one it was in orbit of?

Comment: @valorum I reverted your edits. Have you never read a Star Wars opening crawl with randomly capitalised words?

Comment: Just because Lucas uses randomly capitalised nonsense doesn't mean we should

Comment: *That's no moon!* It may, however, be a moon of a moon of a planet orbiting a star; some, all, or none of which may be called [Endor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Endor).

Comment: Also plus one for very consistent capitalisation.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I thought Endor was a gas giant of which “the Forest Moon of Endor” was a moon. Has that been retconned?

Comment: @Darren: I'm sure you're right, I can't keep track. I _think_ the one in *The Rise of Skywalker* is a moon orbiting the forest moon (maybe you call that a meta moon?), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I dunno. I thought maybe the planet/astronomical body they were on was another moon of Endor, but not clear at all as you say.

Comment: @Darren: that'd probably make more sense. The other, not-at-all-foresty moon of Endor.

Comment: Star Wars fall on the trope Tematical Planets. If they aren't practically identical is because they  are different planets.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [*Rise of Skywalker Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) and [*Rise of Skywalker: The Galactic Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Galactic_Guide) identify the object in question as IX3244-C, otherwise known as the ***Ocean Moon of Endor*** or ***[Kef Bir](https://disneyparks.disney.go.com/blog/2019/12/star-tours-at-disney-parks-begins-service-to-new-destinations-inspired-by-star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker/)***

> Kef Bir is one of many moons that orbits the giant gas planet Endor.
>   This moon  is covered in oceans, with some grassy islands emerging
>   from the waters.  Herds of wild orbak creatures live here
>
> <sub><sup>[Rise of Skywalker: The Galactic Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Galactic_Guide)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[*Rise of Skywalker: Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

Comment: “site of the battle of Endor” — I don’t think they really thought about what that would mean in  an orbital system…

Comment: @PLL - I'm not a rocket scientist, but I'm reasonably sure that when things explode in space, they can achieve escape velocity

Comment: @Valorum, that's not how Star Wars universe physics works. Asteroid fields are examples of that: in our universe such configuration is not stable, our gravity and "celestial mechanics" won't allow it.

Comment: @PLL *That's* your quibble, and not the ridiculous crossing orbits? :)

Comment: @DavidW: Those orbits may be impossible, but they at least make sense as a concept.  What would a fixed “site” in a solar system even *mean*?

Comment: @PLL From the way it's depicted in the image, I read it as being as being in orbit around the Forest Moon.  Which, while unstable, is at least arguable.